# mod_rewrite add trailing slash without losing post data

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post

I am using the following htaccess code to add a trailing slash to urls.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /myvarld/$1/ [R,L]
```

Everything works very fine, but the issue comes when I am trying to post data (like in ajax requests and form submissions) to urls without trailing slash. Apparently, server adds a trailing slash and issues a redirect but drops all post data.
Please suggest a way to solve the problem.

Comment: A simple way to solve this would be to add a trailing slash in all your concerned links

Comment: That is true and is what I am doing right now. But many a times I forget adding the slash. I was wondering if there is any way this could be done through htaccess

Comment: Since you're using an external redirect (by the way, you don't need `L` flag in your rule), it is impossible to preserve `POST` data. What you could do is using `P` flag (instead of `R` flag) but you have to enable `mod_proxy`. This way, i think `POST` data will be preserved